MS Excel, Find out how many items a cell describes
I have created an Excel spreadsheet that lists comics in a collection. For each comic there is a row of data. One cell contains a list of the editions for that comic. An example of this is:
1-3,5-7,12-23, 25,28-34,36-38,43.
So I have issue 1 to 3, 5 to 7, 12 to 23, 25 etc.
I should have counted the totals for each comic, but I wonder if there is a way to "count" the number of comics for each type from my issue list?
Thanks

Thank you everyone who offered a solution.

We need to:
a) split the string on commas, to get the unique ranges, and
b) split each range on hyphen to calculate how many items are represented therein.
If the range is two numbers, then we calculate INDEX(p,,2)-INDEX(p,,1)+1.
If the range is just a single number, we can make it into the same format with INDEX(p,,1)-INDEX(p,,1)+1.
Then, the only variable component is the column index of the first call to INDEX, which we can provide by calculating the COUNT of numbers in the result of splitting by hyphen.
We MAP the function to calculate (b) over the array achieved from (a) and then SUM the result.
=SUM(
    MAP(
        TEXTSPLIT(B2, ","),
        LAMBDA(s,
            LET(
                p, --TEXTSPLIT(s, "-"),
                INDEX(p, , COUNT(p)) - INDEX(p, , 1) + 1
            )
        )
    )
)



What's that ExcelLabs thing?

@BruceWayne It's an Add-In published by Microsoft. It has three tools in it: The Advanced Formula Environment (shown in the image), GENERATIVE.AI - a way to send calls to ChatGPT from a function (not very good tbh) and a beta version of the Python Editor. It's free. You can get it from the Add-Ins button on the ribbon. Recommended.

If you have Excel 365, you can use this thing:
=LET(step1,VALUE(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-",","))),step2,BYROW(step1,LAMBDA(val,IFERROR(INDEX(val,1,2)-INDEX(val,1,1)+1,1))),SUM(step2))


LET() takes in variable names and values and then stores those values for later reference by the variable name.
step1,VALUE(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-",","))) splits your text into rows (when there's a comma) and columns (when there's a hyphen), trims all whitespace, and then converts it from text to a numerical value. The resulting array is stored as step1.
step2,BYROW(step1,LAMBDA(val,IFERROR(INDEX(val,1,2)-INDEX(val,1,1)+1,1))) looks way more complex (to me, at least) but it goes through each row of step1 and subtracts the first value from the second. If there is no second value, then step1 has an error so we use IFERROR() to return a 1 in that instance.
SUM(step2) adds up the result.



The issue counter as a separate Python script:
#!/bin/env python

def issues(lst='1-3,5-7,12-23, 25,28-34,36-38,43.'):
    L=0
    x=lst.split(",")
    for rng in x:
        rng=rng.strip('. ')
        if '-' in rng:
            a,b=rng.split('-')
            a=int(a)
            b=int(b)+1
        else:
            a=int(rng)
            b=a+1
        
        r=range( a, b ) 
        print(
            f'{rng:>6}',
            '\t',a,b,
            '\t',L,'-',
            ','.join( [ f'{z}' for z in r] ) 
            )
        L+=len(r)
    return L

print(issues())

Note: Certain versions of Excel can run python scripts, but only by sending them into the cloud.
The code: The two print() statements is there to allow verifying the correct output, with the example issues list as default parameter to the function.
An example run, as is:
$ python ./issues.py 
   1-3   1 4     0 - 1,2,3
   5-7   5 8     3 - 5,6,7
 12-23   12 24   6 - 12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
    25   25 26   18 - 25
 28-34   28 35   19 - 28,29,30,31,32,33,34
 36-38   36 39   26 - 36,37,38
    43   43 44   29 - 43
30

... remove the print() statements and the remainder is a function that can be imported in pure Python; how to use it in Excel is unknown (for me) at writing this.

I think OP wants to count how many editions of a comic they have not how many groups of numbers they have in the string. They want the "1-3" string to counts as having 3 editions of the comic, "12-23" is 12 editions, etc.

Well, I realized that as I re-read the Q, I see you have it done in Excel-formulas. The Python version above should be possible to launch from the latest Excel though. => https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-python-in-excel-55643c2e-ff56-4168-b1ce-9428c8308545

Ick it runs in the cloud, :-(

One more variant.
This list of numbers can be converted to addresses and the sum of the rows can be counted.
Final formula:
=REDUCE(0, SUBSTITUTE("A"&TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""),","),"-",":A"),
 LAMBDA(a, x, a+ROWS(INDIRECT(x))))




split first by ","
then use TEXTAFTER and TEXTBEFORE to get range end/start

use if_not_found (last) parameter to handle single values (resulting in 1)



enter in B1:
=LET(
    collection, A1:A4,
    count_rng, LAMBDA(rng,
        1 + TEXTAFTER(rng, "-", , , , rng) -
            TEXTBEFORE(rng, "-", , , , rng)
    ),
    count_issues, LAMBDA(csv,
        SUM(MAP(TEXTSPLIT(csv, ","), count_rng))
    ),
    MAP(collection, count_issues)
)


